# If statements with php & Mysql

Tags: php, sql

I need a little bit of your help with if statements in PHP , as I am new to it

First of all I have this query:

```
$sqlCmd = "SELECT user.name,user.level 
    FROM user.user 
    WHERE user.id = '".$_GET['char']."' 
    LIMIT 1";
```

and now I have this second query

```
visible $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user 
    SET level='1' 
    WHERE id='".$_GET['char']."' 
    LIMIT 1";
```

What I want to do is something like this : `if level>1` run the `$sqlUpdate`, else print an error .

Comment: use condition in where

Comment: Show a little more of your code.

Comment: Protect your code against [SQL attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/1037210).

Comment: @Lion  why killing the child

Comment: @Photon : I really didn't get what you meant.

Comment: just a proverb .................

Comment: he does not know the where clause and you are telling for sql attack he just noob

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
visible $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user 
                      SET level='1' 
                      WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['char'])."' 
                      AND level >1 
                      LIMIT 1";
```

refer this links they may help you to learning
http://sqlzoo.net/      ,http://beginner-sql-tutorial.com/sql.htm

Comment: I haven't downvote this. But I think you have given `w3schools` link for reference and because of that someone has downvote you.

Comment: I dont know why but in my case I have started with w3schools...at begining I thought its better lateron you can go through http://sqlzoo.net/

Comment: Nowadays `w3schools` example and code are not proper,they contains lots of mistakes in it and because of that community don't want to give its link for reference. Anyways just remove its link.

Comment: Ok now I think there is no reason to downvote for my CORRECT answer

Answer (score 1):

```
visible $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user SET level='1' WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['char'])."' AND level >1 LIMIT 1";
```

your code is vulnerable to sql injection you need to escape all request properly

---

### **Warning**

your code is vulnerable to [sql injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) you need to escape all `get`, `post` and `request` and the better approach will be using [Prepared statement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement)

**Good Read**

1. [How to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
2. [**Are PDO prepared statements sufficient to prevent SQL injection?**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12202218/1723893)

---

### **Note**

1. The entire **`ext/mysql`** PHP extension, which provides all functions named with the prefix mysql_, is [officially deprecated as of PHP v5.5.0](http://php.net/manual/en/changelog.mysql.php) and will be removed in the future. So use either `PDO` or `MySQLi`

**Good read**

1. [The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13944956/the-mysql-extension-is-deprecated-and-will-be-removed-in-the-future-use-mysqli/13944958#comment19236631_13944958.)
2. [PDO Tutorial for MySQL Developers](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
3. [Pdo Tutorial For Beginners](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-)

Comment: Can you help me to fix that vuln?

Comment: @user1638487 Try to learn prepared statment using `Mysqli` OR `PDO`

Answer (score 0):

```
$sqlCmd = "SELECT user.name,user.level FROM user.user WHERE user.id = '".$_GET['char']."' AND level>1 LIMIT 1";
if(mysql_num_rows($mysql_con)===1){
//run second query
}else{echo'error:'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this should do it...

```
$result = mysql_query($sqlCmd);
if($row = mysql_fetch_object($result)) {
    if ($row->level > 1)
    {
      mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
      //Might want to add a check here if it was successful... 
      echo "Done";
    }
    else
      echo 'error!!!';

}
mysql_free_result($result);
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for , thanks! Now I am trying to add and "correct" msg to the code like "done" , I've tried to add an echo before "mysql_query($sqlUpdate);" , but does not work , any idea?

Comment: did you add appropriate brasses to code? My **if** statement contains only one line, that why i didn't need them before

Comment: I updated the code, let me know if that what you wanted to accomplish.

Comment: Nice , thanks again , now i'd like to add another check in the if . I have tried this :    if ($row->level > 249 & $row->power!=0) But does not work , can you help me again?

Comment: Try using **&&** instead of **&**

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$sqlCmd = "SELECT user.name,user.level 
FROM user.user 
WHERE user.id = '".$_GET['char']."' 
LIMIT 1";

$resource = mysql_query($sqlCmd);
$temp_arr = mysql_fetch_assoc($resource);
$level    = $temp_arr['level'];
if($level > 1)
{
    $sqlUpdate = "UPDATE user.user 
    SET level='1' 
    WHERE id='".mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['char'])."' 
    LIMIT 1";

    mysql_query($sqlUpdate);
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
    mysql_query("UPDATE user.user SET level='1' WHERE id='".$_GET['char']."' and level>1 LIMIT 1");
```